# help - A system consists of springs A and B and objects C and D

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

[image: Question]

Hi all, I have completed the question up to part c). Using matlab, I have found the eigenvectors/eigenvalues but from there I am unsure as to how to find the solution which would comprise of the below frequencies. Also I am unsure as to how to go about part d).

Eigenvalues
0;
0;
-0.382;
-2.618;

Eigenvectors (corresponding)
[1,0,0,0];
[0,1,0,0];
[0.3035,-0.1876,-0.7947,0.4911];
[0.4911,0.7947,-0.1876,-0.3035];

Comment: I believe your G formulation is incorrect. As your eigenvalues indicate an unstable system. For the last part you only revert back to your original time variable and should rescale the frequency values. If you accept 0.5s as your unit time instead of 1s then a phenomena occurring at 1 Hz (in 1s scale) happens at 2Hz. (Time frequency multiplication stays the same)

Comment: what did you get for G? @keoxkeox